# Stopping an externally loaded swf from "playing" when another external swf is loaded (AS 3)

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm creating a portfolio with flash swf files and I load them externally!

I have a homepage with five "links" to each swf. Now the first swf I have a custom cursor that hides the mouse. When I click on that link it plays and when I quickly go to the homepage again it hides the mouse there when it's not supposed to do it.

Same with every other link. When I was busy with the first swf and want to go to the last swf of the five, my mouse just disappears! It is almost as if it keeps on "playing" without seeing the swf...

It's rather difficult to explain so I hope you understand what I mean!

Here is the code that I have so far!

```
var currentpage:uint = 0;

//one loader object per project:
var loadingobject1:Loader = new Loader();
loadingobject1.x = 445;
loadingobject1.y = 160;
var loadingobject2:Loader = new Loader();
loadingobject2.x = 488;
loadingobject2.y = 180;
var loadingobject3:Loader = new Loader();
loadingobject3.x = 510;
loadingobject3.y = 223;
var loadingobject4:Loader = new Loader();
loadingobject4.x = 510;
loadingobject4.y = 223;
var loadingobject5:Loader = new Loader();
loadingobject5.x = 455;
loadingobject5.y = 175;

button_home.buttonMode = true;
button_home.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pageswitch0);
button_project1.buttonMode = true;
button_project1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pageswitch1);
button_project2.buttonMode = true;
button_project2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pageswitch2);
button_project3.buttonMode = true;
button_project3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pageswitch3);
button_project4.buttonMode = true;
button_project4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pageswitch4);
button_project5.buttonMode = true;
button_project5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pageswitch5);

button_home.visible = false;
BG.visible = false;
sound_control_home.visible = true;
Mouse.show();

//HEADERS//
T1.visible = false;
T2.visible = false;
T3.visible = false;
T4.visible = false;
T5.visible = false;

SoundMixer.stopAll();

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //////////////////////  Sound  ///////////////////////
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        var default_volume_home:Number = 0.85; // 0.00 to 1.00
        var background_music:Sound = new homepage_music();
        var music_channel_home:SoundChannel = background_music.play(0, 10000);
        var music_volume_home:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform();
        music_volume_home.volume = default_volume_home;
        music_channel_home.soundTransform = music_volume_home;

        sound_control_home.stop();
        sound_control_home.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, play_pause_home );

        function play_pause_home(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            music_volume_home.volume = default_volume_home;

            if( e.target.currentFrame == 1 )
                music_volume_home.volume = 0;

            music_channel_home.soundTransform = music_volume_home;
            e.target.play();
        }

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////// PAGESWITCH 0 //////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////  Homepage  ///////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function pageswitch0(m:MouseEvent)
{
    if (currentpage != 0)//making sure the page isn't already selected
    {
        //testing which page is currently visible and unloading it (note in the other functions that if it's the home page the visibility is just set to false):
        if (currentpage == 1)
        {
            loadingobject1.unload();
        }
        else if (currentpage == 2)
        {
            loadingobject2.unload();
        }
        else if (currentpage == 3)
        {
            loadingobject3.unload();
        }
        else if (currentpage == 4)
        {
            loadingobject4.unload();
        }
        else if (currentpage == 5)
        {
            loadingobject5.unload();
        }
        homepage.visible = true;//making the home page visible
        SoundMixer.stopAll();
        Mouse.show();

        var default_volume_home:Number = 0.7;
        var background_music:Sound = new homepage_music();
        var music_channel_home:SoundChannel = background_music.play(0, 10000);
        var music_volume_home:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform();
        music_volume_home.volume = default_volume_home;
        music_channel_home.soundTransform = music_volume_home;

        sound_control_home.stop();
        sound_control_home.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, play_pause_home );

        function play_pause_home(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            music_volume_home.volume = default_volume_home;

            if( e.target.currentFrame == 1 )
                music_volume_home.volume = 0;

            music_channel_home.soundTransform = music_volume_home;
            e.target.play();
        }

        currentpage = 0;//setting the currentpage variable to the correct value
        button_home.visible = false;
        BG.visible = false;
        sound_control_home.visible = true;

        //HEADERS
        T1.visible = false;
        T2.visible = false;
        T3.visible = false;
        T4.visible = false;
        T5.visible = false;
    }
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////// Theme 1 /////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////// PAGESWITCH 1 //////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function pageswitch1(m:MouseEvent)
{   
    Mouse.show();
    if (currentpage != 1)
    {
        if (currentpage == 0)
        {
            homepage.visible = false;
        }
        else if (currentpage == 2)
        {
            loadingobject2.unload();
        }
        else if (currentpage == 3)
        {
            loadingobject3.unload();
        }
        else if (currentpage == 4)
        {
            loadingobject4.unload();
        }
        else if (currentpage == 5)
        {
            loadingobject5.unload();
        }
        //loading an external file
        var whattoload:URLRequest = new URLRequest("start.swf");
        loadingobject1.load(whattoload);
        addChild(loadingobject1);
        currentpage = 1;
        button_home.visible = true;
        BG.visible = true;
        sound_control_home.visible = false;
        SoundMixer.stopAll();
        Mouse.show();

        //HEADERS
        T1.visible = true;
        T2.visible = false;
        T3.visible = false;
        T4.visible = false;
        T5.visible = false;
    }
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////// Theme 2 /////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////// PAGESWITCH 2 //////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function pageswitch2(m:MouseEvent)
{
    Mouse.show();
    if (currentpage != 2)
    {
        if (currentpage == 0)
        {
            homepage.visible = false;
        }
        else if (currentpage == 1)
        {
            loadingobject1.unload();
        }
        else if (currentpage == 3)
        {
            loadingobject3.unload();
        }
        else if (currentpage == 4)
        {
            loadingobject4.unload();
        }
        else if (currentpage == 5)
        {
            loadingobject5.unload();
        }
        var whattoload:URLRequest = new URLRequest("Theme_2.swf");
        loadingobject2.load(whattoload);
        addChild(loadingobject2);
        loadingobject2.scaleX = 0.99;
        loadingobject2.scaleY = 0.99;
        currentpage = 2;
        button_home.visible = true;
        BG.visible = true;
        sound_control_home.visible = false;
        SoundMixer.stopAll();

        //HEADERS
        T1.visible = false;
        T2.visible = true;
        T3.visible = false;
        T4.visible = false;
        T5.visible = false;
    }
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////// Theme 3 /////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////// PAGESWITCH 3 //////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function pageswitch3(m:MouseEvent)
{
    Mouse.show();
    if (currentpage != 3)
    {
        if (currentpage == 0)
        {
            homepage.visible = false;
        }
        else if (currentpage == 1)
        {
            loadingobject1.unload();
        }
        else if (currentpage == 2)
        {
            loadingobject2.unload();
        }
        else if (currentpage == 4)
        {
            loadingobject4.unload();
        }
        else if (currentpage == 5)
        {
            loadingobject5.unload();
        }
        var whattoload:URLRequest = new URLRequest("Theme_3.swf");
        loadingobject3.load(whattoload);
        addChild(loadingobject3);
        loadingobject3.scaleX = 0.99;
        loadingobject3.scaleY = 0.99;
        SoundMixer.stopAll();
        currentpage = 3;
        button_home.visible = true;
        BG.visible = true;
        T1.visible = false;
        T2.visible = false;
        T3.visible = true;
        T4.visible = false;
        T5.visible = false;
        sound_control_home.visible = false;
    }
}


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////// Theme 4 /////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////// PAGESWITCH 4 //////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function pageswitch4(m:MouseEvent)
{   
    Mouse.show();
    if (currentpage != 4)
    {
        if (currentpage == 0)
        {
            homepage.visible = false;
        }
        else if (currentpage == 1)
        {
            loadingobject1.unload();
        }
        else if (currentpage == 2)
        {
            loadingobject2.unload();
        }
        else if (currentpage == 3)
        {
            loadingobject3.unload();
        }
        else if (currentpage == 5)
        {
            loadingobject5.unload();
        }
        //loading an external file:
        var whattoload:URLRequest = new URLRequest("Theme_4.swf");
        loadingobject4.load(whattoload);
        addChild(loadingobject4);
        SoundMixer.stopAll();
        loadingobject4.scaleX = 0.65;
        loadingobject4.scaleY = 0.65;
        currentpage = 4;
        button_home.visible = true;
        BG.visible = true;
        sound_control_home.visible = false;

        //HEADERS
        T1.visible = false;
        T2.visible = false;
        T3.visible = false;
        T4.visible = true;
        T5.visible = false;
    }
}


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////// Theme 5 /////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////// PAGESWITCH 5 //////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function pageswitch5(m:MouseEvent)
{   
    Mouse.show();
    if (currentpage != 5)
    {
        if (currentpage == 0)
        {
            homepage.visible = false;
        }
        else if (currentpage == 1)
        {
            loadingobject1.unload();
        }
        else if (currentpage == 2)
        {
            loadingobject2.unload();
        }
        else if (currentpage == 3)
        {
            loadingobject3.unload();
        }
        else if (currentpage == 4)
        {
            loadingobject4.unload();
        }
        //loading an external file:
        var whattoload:URLRequest = new URLRequest("T5.swf");
        loadingobject5.load(whattoload);
        addChild(loadingobject5);
        SoundMixer.stopAll();
        loadingobject5.scaleX = 0.78;
        loadingobject5.scaleY = 0.78;
        currentpage = 5;
        button_home.visible = true;
        BG.visible = true;
        sound_control_home.visible = false;

        //HEADERS
        T1.visible = false;
        T2.visible = false;
        T3.visible = false;
        T4.visible = false;
        T5.visible = true;
    }
}
```

PLEASE help if you can!

Thanks a lot!!!

J

Comment: Perhaps you can post the webpage you mention, so we can see the behavior in action?

Answer (score 0):

You won't have any success in preventing that behavior, if you can't modify the loaded swf.

If you are able to modify the loaded swf, you should call `Mouse.hide()` only, if your clip is added to the stage (by listening to `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE`) and call `Mouse.show()` if its removed from the display list (by listening to `Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE`).

In you loader clip, be sure, to only add the loaded clip with `addChild()` when you actually need to show it and remove it with `removeChild()` when it's no longer needed. This will trigger the listeners described above which take care of showing and hiding the mouse.